# Installing Windows Service Multiple Times InstallShield Limited Edition

Tags: wix, installshield, multiple-instances

We have a windows service which is installed using the free Limited Edition of InstallShield, we use a Wix wxs file to install the windows service.

The problem we now have is that we want to be able to install the service twice or more on the same machine pointing at different databases which may be at different versions which is why we need a separate instance per database.

In an ideal world during the install we would choose a directory and name and that would be the service name and we can do this as many times as we want.

Is this possible with the limited edition, if not is this possible with the paid versions?  I have tried researching and we are getting conflicted information.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called multiple instance installers.  InstallShield LE doesn't support this.  InstallShield Professional does. I've done many of these and the learning curve is a bit steep but very possible.